# Map/Replace values from one column with lookup to values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Three dataframes. In `DataFrame1`, how to replace the values from columns `From_` and `To_`  with the corresponding values in column `Name` in `DataFrame2` (for `To_`) and `DataFrame3` (for `From_`)? Note that values for `From_` and `To_` in `DataFrame1` are index references that start at 1 and not 0. So value 2 in `To_` should reference `Name2` in `DataFrame2`. Thank you very much for your help.

DataFrame1:

```
    S    From_   To_
0   x    NaN     None
1   x    NaN     None
2   x    NaN     None
3   x    1.0     2
4   x    1.0     5
5   x    NaN     None
6   x    NaN     None
7   x    NaN     None
8   x    NaN     None
9   x    NaN     None
10  x    1.0     NaN
```

DataFrame2:

```
     A   Name
0  None  Name1
1  None  Name2
2  None  Name3
3  None  Name4
4  None  Name5
```

DataFrame3:

```
     A   Name
0  None  Name6
1  None  Name7
2  None  Name9
3  None  Name10
```

How to change `DataFrame1` to look like this:

```
    S    From_     To_
0   x    NaN       None
1   x    NaN       None
2   x    NaN       None
3   x    Name6     Name2
4   x    Name6     Name5
5   x    NaN       None
6   x    NaN       None
7   x    NaN       None
8   x    NaN       None
9   x    NaN       None
10  x    Name6     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a `map`

```py
df1['From_'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['From_'], errors='coerce').sub(1).map(df3['Name'])
df1['To_']   = pd.to_numeric(df1['To_'], errors='coerce').sub(1).map(df2['Name'])
```

```
    S  From_    To_
0   x    NaN    NaN
1   x    NaN    NaN
2   x    NaN    NaN
3   x  Name6  Name2
4   x  Name6  Name5
5   x    NaN    NaN
6   x    NaN    NaN
7   x    NaN    NaN
8   x    NaN    NaN
9   x    NaN    NaN
10  x  Name6    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly after I add the pd.to_numeric to the df1['From_']